# Bootstrap4 set col height to minimum in row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Given this layout of images, how can I set the right column to crop the image height and set its height to equal the left column (with bottom of images aligning)? This only needs to work on lg+ if that matters.

Prefer Bootstrap 4 solution with no jQuery if possible.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 30px;" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/199/sunflowers-6-1392951.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 30px;" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/199/sunflowers-6-1392951.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid" style="" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/5e6/clouds-1396327.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/qGtub1szCU

edit: fixed link

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this without some kind of specific mesure or js. The problem is if you want it to be fluid but you also want the left elements to be half the one in the right. It's possible to do it if you want the whole thing to have, let´s say, 100% the window height or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem? if not please let me know.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 30px;"
                            src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/199/sunflowers-6-1392951.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-fluid"
                            src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/199/sunflowers-6-1392951.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="h-100">
            <a href="#" class="d-flex h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid" style=""
                    src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/5e6/clouds-1396327.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```